# php get data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

here is a code to fetch data from MySQL database

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons
WHERE FirstName='Peter'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];
  echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

my question is what if the database have more than 10,000,000 rows
how php could handle this 
i mean $result will pass memory_limit that is located in php.ini  ????

Comment: Ideally you would use pagination.

Comment: I don't think there's 10 million people named peter in all of the world not to mention in your database. Not to be funny but think about your application and your queries and their expected result sets. Would you ever have to return that many rows?

Comment: mister martin and Thorsten
your comments was useful to me
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$result** WON'T pass the memory limit because it doesn't contain all the results you've selected from your table. It's simply a *pointer* to the results. When you do a *$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)*, only then are results stored in memory, but only a single row, not every single result.

Do an "echo($result);" and see the output for yourself. It's a simple pointer to a resource.

Nevertheless, be conservative when selecting data from your SQL server. Use only what you need, especially if you have data *blobs* or *longtext* columns.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Persons WHERE FirstName='Peter'
```

This will still select all the rows from your table, and if you need to eventually *echo* these results to the browser, you may need to limit the number of selected rows, and to do so, you'll use the obvious mySQL "LIMIT" clause:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Persons WHERE FirstName='Peter' LIMIT 10
```

This will select only the first 10 results from your table. Do a "SELECT COUNT(*)" to find the number of rows in your table so that you can implement pagination, but that's a different story.